# Force user to have the latest version of an app

Tags: android

Is it possible to check on startup of an Android app whether the user has the latest version of it and force him to update if he has not?
Or at least checkt whether there is a new version and tell him, that the app only will work again when he downloads and installs the update?

Background is that I have an app that needs to communicate with a server. When I change something in the interface between server and client I want to assure that the client has the latest version.

Is there any native way to do this? Or do I have to check this on my own?

Comment: This open source GitHub project (MAHAndroidUpdater)is completely providing update functionality. Try it, Very simple. https://github.com/hummatli/MAHAndroidUpdater

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a native way to do this -- but coding it yourself shouldn't be too hard ; you'll have to :

- Implement a version check : make a request to your server, and have your server return the last version number
- Then, if the version number gotten from the server is higher that the application's one, ask the user to update.

You could even do this at each request -- just include the version number in each response from the server.

*Might be useful in case the user resumes the application, instead of re-starting it from your "first" activity.*