# Best strategy for ensuring users are always using the latest version of your Android app?

Tags: android

I'm wondering what techniques Android developers are using to ensure that (almost) all users are using the latest version of their app?  I'm getting close to releasing my first Android application and anticipate an iterative release schedule.  I'd like to avoid the situation where we find ourselves having to support a dozen different versions in the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribute your app via the Android Market. Users will be notified of updates. Depending on user preference, the app may even auto-update when a new version is released.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Force user to have the latest version of an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390457/force-user-to-have-the-latest-version-of-an-app)